# I want to add vue js components during runtime to my webapp. How do I do this the best?

Tags: vue.js, dynamic, runtime, vue-dynamic-components

I want to have a vue js web application where users can add new components. I want these components to be compiled during runtime and added to the dist folder, so the system can be lightweight. Then users can see the changes they made without having to restart the system. A refresh is possible but not optimal. 
I'm not that experienced with vue.js so I don't know where to start, what I should use...

If you have any idea please feel free to answer
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with NPM run watch to your web app and you can start from Below URL's

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

Thanks,
Mallik